# How can I output an array of functions given a variable having a list within

Tags: python, arrays

I have a variable `f` that is an array of functions

```
import numpy as np
import random

f = np.array([np.sin(x)-np.cos(x), np.cos(2*x), np.sin(x)+np.cos(x), (np.cos(x)**2), (np.sin(x)**2)])
```

and I have created a variable `x` which is

```
random.seed(5)
x = np.array(np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi)for j in range(5)).reshape(5,1)for i in range(0,2)
```

The variable x produces 2 random 5by1 vectors, e.g.

```
[array([[2.83299959],
        [3.0761472 ],
        [3.31156297],
        [5.32141915],
        [5.80267552]]), array([[0.50920597],
        [1.28818661],
        [4.60886743],
        [5.1166359 ],
        [5.66032732]])]
```

My goal is to have the function `f` output a 2 5by1 vectors just like the output of `x`. ie

```
f = array([[np.sin(2.832..)-np.cos(2.832..), np.cos(2*3.07.), np.sin(3.311..)+np.cos(3.311..),(np.cos(5.321..)**2), (np.sin(5.802..)**2)]]), 
          array([[np.sin(0.509..)-np.cos(0.509..), np.cos(2*1.288..), np.sin(4.608..)+np.cos(4.608..), (np.cos(5.116..)**2), (np.sin(5.660..)**2)]])
```

Comment: `f` is not an array of functions; it's just an array of values. The expression you assign to `f` isn't valid until you have *already* defined `x`, at which it will evaluate to the array of numbers you show. Your goal isn't achievable by any simple (if any at all) means.

Comment: An array of functions would be something like `f = np.array([lambda x: np.sin(x) - np.cos(x), lambda x: np.cos(2*x), ...])`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So i just have to change the array assigned to f and see if it works.

Comment: It's certainly not going to make the output of `f` look like unevaluated calls to the various trig functions. That's the part that I doubt is achievable.

Comment: Oh boy, okay. I will play around it and see. But what do you recommend i do to achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't have any recommendations, because I don't think it's achievable. Python simply isn't designed to do this.

Comment: Should f contain array of results or really unevaluated functions?

Comment: Yes, f should contain array of results